# Viewing mp4 file on shared hard drive with VLC

Tags: arch-linux, vlc

I have a hard drive shared in my local network (from windows). I'm accessing it via Dolphin with almost no issues (sometimes I have to input password 10 times before it lets me enter), but when I open any video with VLC, it shows `your input can't be opened`. I presume VLC just expects it to be a local folder, or just has issues with shared folders and fails to open it, but I'm almost sure that there is a way to config it in a way it will view it. But I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/vlc-remote-files.html)

Comment: @EmilioGalarraga SMB is not available as one of the inputs.

Comment: @EmilioGalarraga ok, there is no SMB, but there is libdsm SMB input available, and it kinda does the trick. I honestly guess it does work, but for some reason connection is very moody, it works 1% of the time. Might be related to need of typing in password 10-20 times before it connects. Connection from android works with 0 issues. I guess linux has its limits.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.